# Linux container run on Windows has different time

Tags: docker, datetime, time

I work on Windows 10. I use a docker image based on Ubuntu 18.04 (`FROM ubuntu:18.04`). When I run a Linux container using Docker the time returned by "`date`" command differs from the time on the Windows host machine. The time in the container is two hours earlier than in the host machine. I have updated Docker to the newest version. How to fix that ?

**Edit1**: Docker uses Linux containers - I see the option "Switch to Windows containers..."

**Edit2**: Maybe I can use `hwclock` command ? `sudo hwclock --debug` shows the following output:

```
hwclock from util-linux 2.31.1
System Time: 1690445278.534910
Trying to open: /dev/rtc0
Trying to open: /dev/rtc
Trying to open: /dev/misc/rtc
No usable clock interface found.
hwclock: Cannot access the Hardware Clock via any known method.
```

Answer (score 0):

docker containers are in UTC time, if you are in WSL you can mount the file /etc/localtime:

```
volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
```

Comment: Is it possible to achieve that without Dockerfile modification ?

Comment: you don't have to edit the dockerfile, just mount the /etc/localtime file, e.g. `docker run -it --rm -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime ubuntu:18.04 date`

Comment: The above comment doesn't switch to the terminal in the container - only prints incorrect datetime

Comment: exactly, it's an example to read the correct date, to launch the contaiener just do `docker run -it --rm -v /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime ubuntu:18.04 bash`, this work if you are in WSL and `date` in WSL must be correct

Comment: After executing the above command the ```date``` command in the linux container still returns datetime which is two hours earlier than in the windows host machine.

Comment: You are in WSL or docker desktop? this work in WSL and correct datetime

Comment: I use Docker Desktop and I run docker commands using windows cmd scripts or powershell terminal. When I run Ubuntu terminal using WSL the datetime is sync with the host machine.